# java StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

Its a very simple function. I don't know why it is giving an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for the function source.charAt(i). I have checked the values of 'i' are not exceeding the length of the string which will be always 9.

```
public static String getClockResetString(String source, String target, Hashtable order)
{
    String temp = "",name;

    for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++){
        name = (String)order.get(""+i);

                if(source.charAt(i) != target.charAt(i))
                {
                    if((int)source.charAt(i) < (int)target.charAt(i)){
                        temp = "h" + name + "=" + "dp" + name + "0" + " do " + "{h" + name + "'=0, k'=k+1} ";
                    }
                    else{
                        temp = "h" + name + "=" + "dn" + name + "1" + " do " + "{h" + name + "'=0, k'=k+1} ";
                    }
                }

    }

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: what arguments are you passing to this method ? `source` is empty.

Comment: The exception doesn't lie.

Comment: Probably `target` is shorter than `source`.

Comment: Given the exception, it looks like one of your strings is an empty string... Also, uh, why use a `Hashtable` in 2015? It has been obsoleted for at least 10 years...

Comment: its a gene sequence of 9 bits. its an old code of my supervisor. source and target are not empty. order is also working. Exception is popping for a few states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that you are exceeding the bounds on target, not source

```
if(source.charAt(i) != target.charAt(i))
```

You need to check that

```
i < target.length()
```